# How to updateQueries when the Query contain edges and node with Apollo?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I use react-apollo on my React application for request a GraphQL API. I want to add an item and update my query after this add.

The item is added correctly but I can't update my query. I have to refresh my page to see my new item. I follow [this guide](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#updateQueries).

This is **my query**:

```
export const allCodeReviews = gql`
  query allCodeReviews {
  allCodeReviews {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        reference
        reviewer
        revisionDate
        redmineUrl
        flow {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is **my mutation which add my new item**:

```
this.props.mutate({
   variables: {
    "reviewer": "john",
    "revisionDate": "2016-11-11",
     "flow": "foo",
     "redmineUrl": "foo.com",
     "reference": "#bar"
   },
   updateQueries: {
    allCodeReviews: (prev, {mutationResult}) => {
      const addedReview = mutationResult.data.addCodeReview.codeReview;
       console.log(addedReview);
       console.log(prev);
       return update(prev, {
         allCodeReviews: {
           edges: {
             $unshift: [addedReview]
           }
         }
       });
     }
   }
 });
```

How to update this query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try with: `$unshift: [{node: addedReview}]`. Depending on your `addCodeReview` mutation.

Comment: Yes, it's works! There was also an error on a date format (for "revisionDate" variable) that prevented updateQueries to work whereas the item was correctly added in database.